# Sum Numbers Up to First "/"

Tags: microsoft-excel, array

I have an array of numbers like this:

```
114/114
142/137
79/79
60/59
69/69
132/132
1/1
```

I need to total the numbers before and after the "/", ending up with 597/591. Is this possible in Excel 2016?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SUMRPRODUCT and parse the array then concatenate back:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(A1:A7,FIND("/",A1:A7)-1))&"/"&SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1:A7,FIND("/",A1:A7)+1,10))
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you, thank you!

Comment: Please conside marking correct by clicking the check mark by the answer

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to suggest two possible methods:*

**Method 1:**

[image]

- Formula in cell F16 (fill down):

  `=LEFT(E16,FIND("/",E16)-1)`
- Formula in cell G16 (fill down):

  `=REPLACE(E16,1,FIND("/",E16),"")`
- Enter this array (CSE) formula in cell F22 & fill Right.

  `{=SUMPRODUCT((F16:F21)*1)}`

**Note,,** finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

---

**Method 2:**

[image]

- Array (CSE) formula is cell E22, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

  ```
   {=SUM(LEFT(E16:E21,FIND("/",E16:E21)-1)+0)&"-"&SUM(RIGHT(E16:E21,LEN(E16:E21)-FIND("/",E16:E21))+0)}
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*